# How can I view stdout for an RCP built in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, powershell, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm attempting to write a plugin for an RCP application.

I started with the Hello World plugin template in Eclipse. Ran it. Saw it worked in Eclipse. Exported it and dropped the jar into the `plugin` directory for the RCP application and started that application. It didn't add the new menu.

I changed the code to instead just have a popup on startup (using the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point.)

I ran that. Saw it worked in Eclipse. Exported and dropped into the RCP application. It doesn't show the popup.

So... I think at this point I want to somehow view the stdout/stderr for the RCP application. I could add in a simple message that goes to stdout on startup in the plugin and see if that shows up. I could also check it for errors, to see if maybe it says there was somekind of error in loading my plugin or something.

The issue is, when I launch the application from PowerShell, it immediately returns the prompt. How do I end up viewing the stdout/stderr from the application?

Comment: did you try "java -jar launcher" from power shell?

Comment: may be helpful https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/200021/

Comment: @ArdeshanaMilan - Thanks! That link had the exact answer I needed. It appears that the way to launch an rcp in Windows PowerShell is: `.\jre\bin\java.exe -jar plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_[...].jar`. Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to launch eclipse application from CMD is `java -jar "%EQUINOXJAR%"`

Reference

1. [Eclipse Wiki Starting_Eclipse_Commandline_With_Equinox_Launcher](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Starting_Eclipse_Commandline_With_Equinox_Launcher#Cmd.2FBat_Script)